# socket.io not sending connect message to client on flashsocket

Tags: flash, node.js, socket.io, flashsocket

I'm using node.js server with socket.io plugin to connect between two clients (flash and js) on different devices

for the flash integration I'm using the [FlashSocket.IO](https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO) library 
and have `io.set('transports', ['websocket', 'flashsocket']);` on my .js server file

while everything works fine in most of the computers - on some computers (I don't know if it's relevant but both of the computers that I checked are running Windows 8) - the connection doesn't work

when enabling debug on the server I see that for the working clients the server send `1::` message and for the not-working clients - it doesn't

this is part of the log for working client:

```
  debug - client authorized
  info  - handshake authorized 8JVqPB6MuJYJeMR3RVN_
  debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/flashsocket/8JVqPB6MuJYJeMR3RVN_
  debug - set heartbeat interval for client 8JVqPB6MuJYJeMR3RVN_
  debug - client authorized for
  debug - flashsocket writing 1::
  connected - //my console.log call on io.sockets.on('connection', ...
  debug - flashsocket received data packet 5:0+::{"args":"7087623252","name":"register"}
```

and for the not working client:

```
  debug - client authorized
  info  - handshake authorized 0nztNzwvw260Pa-bRHef
  debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/flashsocket/0nztNzwvw260Pa-bRHef
  debug - set heartbeat interval for client 0nztNzwvw260Pa-bRHef
  debug - client authorized for
  connected - //my console.log call on io.sockets.on('connection', ...
```

p.s.

it doesn't seem like a firewall issue - even when the firewall is off the problem keeps happening

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually it was an antivirus related issue

one second before I got insane I found that the Avast that was installed on that computer blocked the connection - when the Web Shield was disabled - everything worked like a charm

(Installing the same Antivirus on my Win7 machine didn't reproduced the problem - maybe that was Win8+Avast issue)

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a browser related issue. From the [socket.io github page](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO) :

> `flashsocket` will not activate on Chrome or other browsers that fully
>   support WebSockets, even if flashsocket is specified as the only
>   transport. To test flashsocket, use IE 8 or IE 9, or other browsers
>   that don't natively support WebSockets.

So if you want to make sure flashsocket is working correctly use IE 8/9.

Comment: This comment is about fallback to flash on javascript client that doesn't support WebSockets natively - my question was about implementation of socket.io connection inside flash application. moreover, the problem occur on multiple browsers so it is not it - but thanks for your reply anyway!